# Big-O notation based on runtime

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, computer-architecture

I am having a hard time determining the Big-O notation based on the runtime of the algorithm. I would really appreciate it if any one of you could give me some hint/ or tips in answering the question.

[image]

Comment: Impossible to tell exactly from finitely many points, since Big-O is asymptotic. Still, I'd try to plot the _difference_ between each case and the $n=0$, to remove some setup time, and see if that fits e.g. a line.

Comment: 1. You are after [$\Theta$](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10376740/what-exactly-does-big-%d3%a8-notation-represent), not $O$. 2. It looks constant - $\Theta (1)$. 3. Try different orders of magnitude: 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... . 4. No amount of statistical evidence is logically conclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account both of the comments above, you can improve a pretty good answer for your problem by taking different orders of magnitude and then using log-logplot in order to get a polinomal for which your data converges (for instance you can use Lagrange's interpolation theorem result) so you can determine a good approach for the function you're looking for. You can check [this site](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/41analysis/) to get more info about, not only the process I've just described for you, but also about big O notation and theta notation (also known as tilde notation).

Answer (score 1):

Measuring the runtime of an algorithm may give you an educated guess about the time complexity of an algorithm, if used intelligently. That educated guess may be wrong. On the other hand, it may be right, and having a correct guess may make it easier to prove the time complexity.

In your case my educated guess would be a large constant, plus maybe some growing factor, with no good guess possible with your small numbers. Try n = 100, 1000, 10000 and see what happens.

Another effect of measuring the runtime is that it takes account the presence of bugs in your implementation. You might try to implement bubblesort and get linear time in your runtime - that's quite possible if there's a bug in your code. Your array will probably not be sorted :-(